# Printing not working in Visual Studio 2008 Windows Forms Application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, printing

I tried printing a red rectangle in visual studio C++ 2008 using PrintDocument component, this is the code I used:

```
private:
   void printDocument1_PrintPage(System::Object ^ sender,
      System::Drawing::Printing::PrintPageEventArgs ^ e)
   {
      e->Graphics->FillRectangle(Brushes::Red,
         Rectangle(500, 500, 500, 500));
   }
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         printDocument1->PrintPage += gcnew
         System::Drawing::Printing::PrintPageEventHandler
   (this, &Form1::printDocument1_PrintPage);
         }
```

I do have a printer and it works if you're wondering. The code above should print a red rectangle when a button is pressed, however it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Click event handler is wrong, every click adds *another* event handler to PrintPage.  That assignment belongs in the form constructor.  It doesn't work because you forgot the important call, you didn't actually ask it to print.  Fix:

```
    System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        printDocument1->Print();
    }
```

Use PrintPreviewDialog to save a tree.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Can you also tell me how to print an entire dataGridView component (As in, get the data written)?